PhpSpreadsheet only save the first worksheet as csv
I tried to save a specific worksheet from an XLSX as CSV.
First I tried to use setActiveSheetIndexByName() function to set active sheet and call the writer method of \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv, but no luck. Somehow the writer save the first worksheet. I tried indexing by name, by number, but not a little difference.
Now there is a code I experimenting with:
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$spreadsheet = $reader->load('infile.xlsx');
foreach($spreadsheet->getAllSheets() as $sheet)
{
   $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndexByName($sheet->getTitle());
   $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
   $title = $activeSheetgetTitle();
   echo $title . PHP_EOL;
   $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);
   $writer->save($title . '.csv', 2);
}

The console output is as I expected: the list of spreadsheet names.
The file system output is almost as I expected:  a lot of CSV files with proper names.
However the content is the same. I mean bit by bit the same content as the first worksheet. No matter if I change the active sheet.
My question is, how can I save CSV file based on a speficict worksheet?
UPDATE:
If I reorder the worksheets on workbook, I got the CSV I need. But this is merely an instant hack, and it will not work when I'll need to work with more worksheet.

Can't you just pass $sheet to the CSV writer constructor?

@C3roe I already tried that, but that constructor only accept Spreadsheet class objects, which is a full workbook, not a worksheet.

Which version are you using exactly?

@rozsazoltan The latest from github, today downloaded the newest 3.6.0
By the way, the issue is resolved.

The issue is that the \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv is set to export the entire spreadsheet rather than just the active sheet. To fix this and ensure each worksheet is exported to its own CSV file, you need to create a new Spreadsheet object containing only the current sheet in the loop. Here's the corrected code:
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader("Xlsx");
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$spreadsheet = $reader->load('infile.xlsx');

foreach ($spreadsheet->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
    // Create a new spreadsheet for the current sheet
    $singleSheetSpreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();
    $singleSheetSpreadsheet->removeSheetByIndex(0); // Remove default sheet
    $singleSheetSpreadsheet->addExternalSheet($sheet, 0); // Add the current sheet

    // Get the sheet title
    $title = $sheet->getTitle();

    // Output the title to console
    echo $title . PHP_EOL;

    // Write the single sheet to a CSV file
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($singleSheetSpreadsheet);
    $writer->save($title . '.csv');
}


Thanks, this solved my bad mood :) Now the next issue is, to get rid of heap of nulls inserted  sporadically inside the CSV file. But that will be another post.

This is far less efficient than the other answer, which simply involves setting the active sheet, as suggested by the official documentation

The other answer pretty the same what is write to myself at the start of the project. But that is not working as expected. I've tried  to save a worksheet which is only contains 3-4 cells only, to check if the large amount of data kills the process. But no. So while the "other answer" seems to be more efficient, it is not working...


Write a specific worksheet
CSV files can only contain one worksheet. Therefore, you can specify which sheet to write to CSV:
$writer->setSheetIndex(0); // default is 0


Source: Reading and Writing to file - PhpSpreadsheet Docs

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv($spreadsheet);

$currentSheetIndex = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheetIndex();
$writer->setSheetIndex($currentSheetIndex); // or any other one

$writer->save("title.csv");


PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv default sheetIndex - GitHub
setSheetIndex - GitHub


Yes, this is what I learned from the documentation. However the docs not write about writer->save is not about individual sheets, but the whole xlsx. Which is quite strange behaviour.
